# How to detect when game is running on Surface Pro?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that is primarily for PC. But for those who have a surface pro or other tablet that runs windows and is touch screen, I want to know if I need to add some extra code to this:

```
public GameObject thingToMove;

    public float smooth = 2;

    private Vector3 _endPosition;

    private Vector3 _startPosition;

    private void Awake() {
        _startPosition = thingToMove.transform.position;
    }

private Vector3 HandleTouchInput() {
        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)  {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                var screenPosition = Input.GetTouch(i).position;
                _startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); }  }
        return _startPosition; }

    private Vector3 HandleMouseInput() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            var screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;
            _startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition); }
        return _startPosition; }
```

This is how my player moves normally, however.. For the touch screen options I have added this in:

```
public void Update() {


         if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform. || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
         _endPosition = HandleTouchInput(); }
        else {
        _endPosition = HandleMouseInput();  }

    thingToMove.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(thingToMove.transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, _endPosition.y, 0), Time.deltaTime * smooth); 

    }
```

Where the `RuntimePlatform.` is.. Which device do I use for touch screen Windows devices? Would this solve my problem?

Comment: Before even solving that, I recommend reading some [Code Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) about C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detection of a touch screen device, consider using [`SystemInfo.deviceType`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceType.html) rather than checking against every single possible `RuntimePlatform`:

```
if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld) {
    _endPosition = HandleTouchInput();
}
else {
    _endPosition = HandleMouseInput();
}
```

If you absolutely need to know if it's a Surface Pro, you could try combining that with `Application.platform`:

```
if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld) {
    _endPosition = HandleTouchInput();

    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer){
        // (Probably) a Surface Pro/some other Windows touchscreen device?
    }
}
else {
    _endPosition = HandleMouseInput();
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

(I'm not 100% sure if Unity will properly handle a Surface Pro as a `DeviceType.Handheld` or `DeviceType.Desktop`, but it's definitely worth trying.)

Comment: Ahh thank you this is what I needed. It's not that I needed the Surface Pro specifically, just that I wanted to make sure I had full compatibility with touchscreen devices that run Windows. Thanks very much.

Comment: Great, I'm happy I could help you out.